# if: Expression Syntax. then: Command not found

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement

I'm trying to create a simple if statement that takes the first set of input as an argument, then the second input as a file name, then run them against an `egrep` statement.  I keep getting the error:

> if:Expression Syntax. then: Command not found.

here is what I have so far...

```
#!/bin/csh

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
        echo "usage ./Reagan_lab3.sh (-e|-p) input file"
exit 1

fi

if [ $1 == "--e" ]; then
egrep -o "(([0-9]{3})|[0-9]{3})[ -][0-9]{3}[ -][0-9]{4}" $2

elif [ $1 == "--p" ]; then
egrep -o "\b[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\b" $2

else;
echo "please make a selection, -e for email or -p for phone number."

exit 2

fi
```

I haven't been able to find what it's looking for. Any help would be great.

Comment: ...re: other things, btw, you're quoting exactly the wrong thing in `[ $1 == "--e" ]`. The `--e` doesn't need to be quoted -- it can't be interpreted as anything but a three-character string constant. `$1`, on the other hand, can be mishandled *lots* of different ways unless it's quoted as `"$1"`. Same for everywhere you expand `$2` unquoted as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpreter line (first line) names `csh`, but your script syntax looks like a Bourne shell style (`bash`, `ksh`, etc.).

Change that first line to `#!/bin/sh` (or similar), then perhaps run your script through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find other syntax and usage issues.

Comment: I wish I had known about ShellCheck before now, fixed and finished.  Thanks a Ton!